# Statistical mechanics problem: Using expansion to solve for limit $\to 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to complete a simplification for a statistical mechanics problem.

Given $s = \frac{\phi\cdot (2\sigma+s)\cdot e^{\frac{s}{w}}}{\phi\cdot e^{\frac{s}{w}} + (1-\phi)\cdot e^{\frac{s}{\sigma}}}$

In the case where $w\geq \sigma \text{ and } \phi \to 0$, show that $s \approx 2\phi\sigma + O(\phi^2), \hspace{0.5cm} (\phi << 1) $.

I am not able to understand and use the hint provided by the question: *Assume that $s$ can be expanded as $[c\phi+ c'(\phi) +o(\phi^2)]$, then plug this into the expression and proceed to identify the two sides of the equation order by order in $\phi$ to arrive at the result.*

I am confused on how to approach the problem as trivially from the equation of $s$, with $\phi \to 0, s\to 0$.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s$ appears on both sides of this equation, so $s$ depends on $\phi$.  This means your "trivially from the equation" isn't quite true.

Expanding the right-hand side in powers of $s$, we obtain
$$  \frac{\phi (2\sigma+s) \mathrm{e}^{\frac{s}{w}}}{\phi \mathrm{e}^{\frac{s}{w}} + (1-\phi)\mathrm{e}^{\frac{s}{\sigma}}} = 2\sigma \phi - \frac{\phi}{w}(-2w\phi + 2\sigma(\phi-1)+w)s + \cdots  \text{,}$$
so the proposed solution form is consistent with the right-hand side.  (Whatever this power series in $s$ represents, we are requiring it equal $s$.  Since $2\sigma\phi$ is not identically zero, the variables must be related in some complicated way to make the original equality hold.  This complicated relation is what thwarts your "trivially from the equation".)

So let's take the hint.  Set
$$  s = c + c' \phi + O(\phi^2)  $$
and obtain
\begin{align*}
s = c + c' \phi + O(\phi^2) &= \frac{\phi (2\sigma+(c + c' \phi + O(\phi^2))) \mathrm{e}^{\frac{(c + c' \phi + O(\phi^2))}{w}}}{\phi \mathrm{e}^{\frac{(c + c' \phi + O(\phi^2))}{w}} + (1-\phi)\mathrm{e}^{\frac{(c + c' \phi + O(\phi^2))}{\sigma}}}  
\end{align*}
Expanding the right-hand side in powers of $\phi$, we have 
\begin{align*}
s = c + c' \phi + O(\phi^2) &= (c+2\sigma)\mathrm{e}^{\frac{c}{w} - \frac{c}{\sigma}} \phi + O(\phi^2)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Since there is no constant term on the right, $c = 0$, reducing to
$$  s = c' \phi + O(\phi^2) = 2\sigma \phi + O(\phi^2)  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Could you explain how you expanded the RHS in powers of s? And yes, I completely missed the fact that $s$ depends on $\phi$. How were you able to pick this up from the fact that $s$ appears on both sides of the equation?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! I am very grateful for your time!

Comment: @vpy : The expansions are both Taylor polynomial ([Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), but stopped after finitely many terms with the remaining terms collected into a [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) expansions with center $0$, also called Maclaurin series.  It is constructed by taking evaluating successive derivatives to construct the coefficients of the polynomial, as described at the link.

Comment: @vpy : That $s$ depends on everything else might be suspected from "$s = {}$ a complicated expression containing everything else" and is confirmed by the power series in $s$ not being just a constant.  (It is possible to write an expression in one or more variables that is actually constant, hence independent of those variables.  That didn't happen here.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Regarding the first Taylor polynomial in $s$, to compute the derivative with respect to $s$, we have to use the quotient rule, I was surprised that it ended up being simple: $\frac{\phi}{w}(-2\phi + 2\sigma (\phi-1) + w)s$. I guess the derivative simplifies further when we evaluate at $s=0$